# Storyboards not showing correct layout on iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to make my own iOS application for the iPhone 5, I have added 3 labels and one button, problem is one button shows up, however the one of the other buttons and the label are cropped ever so slightly and the last button is out of sight.

I know this is to make it so developers only need to design one GUI for all devices, however I don't know how to fix this.

Example error:

**StoryBoard Design**

[image]

**Running on iPhone 5 simulator**

[image]

How would I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you have multiplatofrm app. Can you paste here your storyboard code?

Comment: if the storyboard is in freeform, you need to have constraints for the all the there labels

Comment: @Szu I have not added any code in my app. This is an iPhone not multi.

Comment: show us your constraints setup, you probably always set the space to the left or right instead of aligning the center

Comment: @luk2302 I have not added any constraints. This is the default 1 page application. I just added buttons and labels.

Comment: Well, there you go: add constraints, please learn at least a tiny bit about the interface builder before asking these kind of veeeery basic questions!

Comment: @luk2302 I had also tried the constraints, however that still messed up the code. If you look at the answer I accepted, that fixes the issue without constraints and is the fix that I was hoping for too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in your question that you are making an app for iPhone5. So,you have to change your view controller screen size in attribute inspector.

**1. select your view controller and change size**

[image]

**2. Now your view controller looks like this**

[image]

Now run project in iPhone 5 simulator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This one is the simplest and easiest way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have mis-used constraints, see below a few solutions on Auto Layout:

Step 1: You can change the base value depending on the view you are working on.

[image: Choose the base device you are working on]

Step 2: Load the assistant editor

[image: Assistant Editor]

Step 3: Bring up the preview mode where you can see how each devise is looking when launching the app.

[image: Preview Mode]

Step 4: Choose which device you would like to work on.

[image: Preview mode]

[image: Click the plus button to choose the devices]

[image: Choose Devices]

Step 5: Add constraints

You can also refer to Apples [Auto Layout Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html) for more information and examples.

[image: Without constraints]

[image: Adding constraints 1]

[image: Adding constraints 2]

[image: Seeing the results]

Comment: How do I do step 4 (choosing my device)?

Comment: Click the plus button once you are on the preview mode on the assistant editor. Check Step 4 again, I added a few more images. Let me know if you have any other questions. Tal